# script to auto-login to ebay using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to write a script to auto-login to ebay using the selenium module in python.

I am able to launch the sign-in page in firefox. Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
firefox_capabilities['binary'] = '/usr/bin/firefox'

driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities)
driver.get("https://signin.ebay.in/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SignIn&ru=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.in%2F")

search_field = driver.find_element("Email or username")
search_field.clear()
search_field.send_keys("My username")
```

But this doesnot seem to work. I can't use

```
find_element_by_id
```

because the id keeps changing dynamically.

```
<input size="40" maxlength="64" name="147630419" id="147630419" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" placeholder="Email or username" class="fld" type="text">
```

This is what the placeholder for email looks like. The placeholder for password is also similar. The "name" and "id" change dynamically.

How can I get through this?

Comment: try xpath `""(//input[@placeholder='Email or username'])[2]"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure about the usage of `driver.find_element()`, but I think in `driver.find_element()` you need to pass in the locator (eg: xPath) of the username field, not the placeholder of input field in string format.

The xPath of username field is `"(//input[@placeholder='Email or username'])[2]"` , so try:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[@placeholder='Email or username'])[2]")`

**UPDATE**

The xPath of password field is `"(//input[@placeholder='Password'])[1]"`

Comment: Hi @Jayesh, Thanks. It has worked for me. The script is now able to enter the username in the field. I just wanted to know what the [2] signifies. I also tried doing the same for the password filed since both the elements look same but it doesnot work.

Comment: @VivekBhageria the xPath `//input[@placeholder='Email or username']` returns 2 elements in an array. Since the 2nd element of array is what we want, that's why I did [2], which basically means select the element at index 2 (indexes start from 1)

Comment: @VivekBhageria I updated my answer to include xPath of password field.

Answer (score 1):

since id is changing dynamically go for xpath. Try this piece code. It works

```
driverInstance.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='pri_signin']/div[4]/span[2]/input").send_keys("Hello")
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `find_element()` method incorrectly as you should pass 2 arguments: `by` and `value`.

You might try below line of code:

```
driver.find_element("css", "input:not(#userid)[placeholder='Email or username']").send_keys("My username")
```

but better to use appropriate `find_element_by_...()` method like the one proposed by @Jayesh Doolani (+1)

Comment: shouldn't it be `By.CSS_SELECTOR ` instead of `"css"`

Comment: It might be `By.CSS_SELECTOR` if `selenium.webdriver.common.by.By` was previously imported. `"css"` is also acceptable

Comment: Hi Anderson. I tried this line of code but it throws the error  `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unknown locator strategy css`.  The one proposed by Jayesh has worked. I now need to get it working for the password field.